# Google API PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-api

When making a query to Google API, it returns this error. I want to get reviews of a location.

This is the API response:

Client error:

`GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXX-i3iqir43rc2tq76ckfvg7olj7ge2iiq7.apps.googleusercontent.com/locations/ChIJHcsfnCEtQg0RguXuY3-mM-M/reviews`

Resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:

> { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Google My Business API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXX before (truncated...) HTTP Status Code: 403 Response Body: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Google My Business API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help", "links": [ { "description": "Google developers console API activation", "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX" } ] }, { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "consumer": "projects/XXXXXXXXXXXX", "service": "mybusiness.googleapis.com" } } ] } }

I think I have everything set up correctly.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I have tested OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and also with Service Accounts.